# Android DateUtils.formatDateTime wrong timezone

Tags: android, timezone

```
String time = DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, 1469602800000, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
```

The result is: `03:00` as expected

My current timezone is: `GMT+3:00 DST`

But how can I get: "`00:00`" if I can't pass the timezone to the `dateformatter`?

I have already tried:

```
TimeZone timeZone = getTimezoneForId("America/Los_Angeles");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1469602800000);

String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.getTime());
```

But I'm getting the same result: "`03:00`"

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution for `DateUtils` without using such a heavy object as `Calendar` or even `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
// Your UTC time in milliseconds:
long timeInMillis = 1469602800000;

// Desired timezone ID:
String timezoneId = "UTC";

java.util.Formatter f = new java.util.Formatter(new StringBuilder(50), Locale.getDefault());
String time = DateUtils.formatDateRange(context, f, timeInMillis, timeInMillis, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME, timezoneId).toString();
```

**EXPLANATION:**

If you look at the source code, you will find that when you call

```
formatDateTime(Context context, long millis, int flags)
```

it returns the result of the call

```
formatDateRange(context, millis, millis, flags);
```

which is implemented as follows:

```
public static String formatDateRange(Context context, long startMillis,long endMillis, int flags) {
Formatter f = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(50), Locale.getDefault());
return formatDateRange(context, f, startMillis, endMillis, flags).toString();
}
```

Again, looking at the source code for

```
formatDateRange(context, f, startMillis, endMillis, flags)
```

you will see the following:

```
return formatDateRange(context, formatter, startMillis, endMillis, flags, null);
```

If you look closely at the last line, you will see that it provides `null` as the `String timezone` parameter. Hence, according to the annotation of the method, it will compute the value for your **local** timezone. Official docs suggest to use `Time.TIMEZONE_UTC`, but that thing is deprecated, so in my solution I set the timezone explicitly (`timezoneId = "UTC"`). You can set any timezone you need, e.g. "Pacific/Honolulu" or even "Asia/Novosibirsk". Here is a link for a [complete list of timezones IDs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13866_04/webconf.904/b10877/timezone.htm).

**PLEASE NOTE**

1. If you want your `time` String to be formatted in a specific locale, initialize the `Formatter` providing that specific locale as an initialization argument.
2. The benefit of the provided solution is that the `time` String will be correctly formatted according to the default locale of the device. But if you want to use a specific format for your time representation, that will also be consistent on all devices, use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem.

You are setting the `TimeZone` for `calendar` object. Howewever, you must set `TimeZone` to your `SimpleDateFormat` as well. Otherwise, `SimpleDateFormat` will receive `calendar.getTime()` but will handle it in your default TimeZone.

So, code below will work:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1469602800000L);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormated = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
dateFormated.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));


String time = dateFormated.format(calendar.getTime());
```

I tested and works fine.

**OR**

You can just do:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormated = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
dateFormated.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
String time = dateFormated.format(1469602800000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setTimeZone()` on your SimpleDateFormat, rather than the Calendar itself:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Using this formatter to return a String from the Calendar object should give the result you're looking for.